# Компилирование и повторная загрузка сборки в runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, assembly, кодогенераторы

Товарищи, кратко опишу ситуацию:

Пишу небольшое расширяемое приложение. Чтобы пользователи могли добавлять собственный функционал, в рамках программы создал интерфейсы, от которых они должны наследовать свои типы

При этом я сделал генерацию кода также и внутри самого приложения для большего удобства

---

Положим, есть такой интерфейс:

```
namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    public interface INamed
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

Далее внутри приложения генерируется следующий код (и кладется в `resultCode`):

```
using MyAppNamespace;

public class Wrapper : INamed
{
    public string Name { get { return "Test"; } } 
}
```

Компилирую это дело:

```
// Указываю, что на выходе мне не нужен исполняемый файл, а также что сборку нужно создать по указанному пути
CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters { GenerateExecutable = false, GenerateInMemory = false, OutputAssembly = $"{SavePath}.dll" };
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(new Uri(GetType().Assembly.CodeBase, UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath); // Добавляю ссылку на текущую сборку для наследования интерфейса
// Получаю результат компиляции
CompilerResults results = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, resultCode);
// Опустим проверки
// Загружаю сборку из массива байт (так как сам файл потом, возможно, может быть удален)
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(results.PathToAssembly));
// Создаю instance типа, который в сборке унаследован от нужного интерфейса
INamed named = (INamed)Activator.CreateInstance(asm.DefinedTypes.First(x => x.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(INamed))).AsType());  
asm = null;
GC.Collect(); // Вычищаю сборку из памяти. По крайней мере, я хочу в это верить
return named;
```

После этого я могу спокойно получать доступ к `named.Name`. 
Через некоторое время объект *"выбрасывается"*, пока пользователь явно не укажет, что хочет его использовать. В таком случае его нужно будет повторно достать из сборки

Но есть одно жирное **но**: если я попытаюсь тем же самым образом загрузить сборку и достать из нее тип во второй раз, то визуально процесс пройдет успешно, но при попытке доступа к `named.Name` вылетит ошибка, что сборка, в которой он определен, не найдена

---

Я могу поправить логику приложения и сделать считывание единоразовым (пожалуй, это будет даже правильнее), но сейчас для меня важно *понимание*, почему же так происходит: при первом считывании все работает как часы, а при втором считывании тем же самым способом из того же самого файла процесс проходит успешно, но объект оказывается *"битым"*, так как при попытке доступа к его свойствам я получу ошибку о том, что сборка не может быть загружена

Comment: Хотя нет. С «единоразовым» я погорячился. Все равно придётся считывать снова и снова при перезапуске

Comment: Вы не проверяете `results` на успешность компиляции. P.S. Отдельная сборка не может быть выгружена, только `AppDomain` целиком.

Comment: @PetSerAl проверяю, не волнуйтесь. Это очень урезанный код, чисто чтобы показать опорные точки

Comment: @PetSerAl то есть сборка остаётся где-то в памяти, и пока она там висит, я не могу считать ее повторно. В этом суть проблемы?

Comment: @PetSerAl спасибо, что навели на мысль! Проблема решилась явным добавлением сборки в текущий `AppDomain` и последующей проверкой на ее наличие в нем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вычищаю сборку из памяти. По крайней мере, я хочу в это верить

Увы, эта вера не имеет оснований. Использованный вами способ загрузки сборки не только не позволяет выгрузить сборку из памяти без выгрузки всего домена приложений, но и при каждом повторном запуске будет грузить сборку с того же пути  заново (иными словами, это хороший способ исчерпать память при длительной работе программы).

Создайте `Dictionary <string, Assembly>` (где string будет путем к файлу) и кэшируйте все загружаемые сборки в нем. Можно использовать вместо пути CRC/хэш файла, если вам нужно как-то учесть само содержимое файла. Или грузить каждую сборку в новый домен приложений, тогда их можно будет выгрузить (вообще, это обычная практика при создании приложений с расширениями).

Comment: Спасибо большое) В итоге и пришёл к описанному Вами способу)